# JavaFX Issues with X-axis string display

Tags: javafx, linechart

I have the following LineChart in my FXML file:

```
    <LineChart fx:id="line_chart">
       <xAxis><CategoryAxis  label="Time" /></xAxis>
       <yAxis><NumberAxis label="Price" /></yAxis>
    </LineChart>
```

In my controller file, I populate my series like the following code:

```
    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    for(int i = 0; i < lineChart_DATA.size(); i++)
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(df.format(lineChart_DATA.get(i).date), 
                    lineChart_DATA.get(i).balance));
    series.setName(GUISet.type);
    line_chart.getData().add(series);
    line_chart.setTitle("Title");
```

When I run my program, the X-axis only displays the last string value. I noticed that by running a second time the same code, the X-axis displays correctly.
Did I miss something in my code ?

Comment: Where is the closing } bracket of the for-loop?

Comment: simmilar code works fine for me all the time. and yes i removed `{` after for loop

Comment: Sorry, the opening bracket is useless. I forgot to mention that I define line_chart like that : @FXML private LineChart<String,Number> line_chart; Is there a way to update the line_chart ?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I am adding the series using a button so the code is inside the hamdlebutton function. Is there something I have to add in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it is a specific bug or maybe I did not use LineChart properly but by disabling the animation of the LineChart, I was able to solve my issue.

```
line_chart.setAnimated(false);
```